# ダンスの先生なんだから、上手なはずですよ

Tags: grammar

ダンスの先生なんだから、上手なはずですよ。  is はずです is work as a noun here ?? as its attached after na adjective

Comment: I don't know the answer, but just as a humble request, even if you know the meaning  (As he/she is a dance instructor, you'd expect / it's not surprising that he/she is good) and your are simply asking for the grammatical term, please consider that people with various level of Japanese skills are reading this, so, as we make this site together, while you hope to get an answer, phrasing out a bit more may help others.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, grammatically speaking, this はず is working as a noun, and dictionaries indeed categorize it as a noun. This noun on its own means something like "natural consequence/estimation":

- 上手な: good (at dancing)
- はず: natural estimation

Of course "goodness's natural estimation" makes no sense in English, and the sentence is normally translated like "he/she must/should be good at dancing".

- [Maggie Sensei: How to use はず ( = hazu)](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/11/14/request-lesson-how-and-when-to-use-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9Ahazu/)
- [Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese: Things that should be a certain way](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/should)

A noun like this is called a 形式名詞 ("formal noun"). Instead of working as an ordinary noun, they play some grammatical role, and it's often hard to translate them using English nouns. Other 形式名詞 include とき ("when"), こと (nominalizer), うち ("during"), とおり ("as/like") and の (explanatory-no). Practically speaking, English speakers may want to just memorize the patterns, rather than worrying too much about their meanings as nouns.