# 冗談のつもり the grammatical explanation

Tags: grammar

Since plain form words can attach to つもり, we can just attach the i-adjective 若い to it as is.

When our plain form word is a NOUN, we'll add a の after it. And for na-adjectives, we add a な after them. For example, later we'll see:

> 冗談{じょうだん}のつもり

in this grammar rule. We attach the つもり with the plain form (noun,adjective,verb). Is this つもり acting as a noun, because when its attached with an adjective, we place a な  in between them, and with noun の.

Comment: BTW, please don't forget to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if your question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You asked a [very similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69446/5010) several days ago. This つもり is another 形式名詞. If you *really* want a meaning as a noun, it would be something like "intention", "plan", "assumption" or "belief". But つもり is usually translated into English without using these nouns.