# Is it possible to make a relative clause & main clause using a formal noun, such as はず?

Tags: relative-clauses

I know that a relative clause and main clause are formed when you have a construct of [sentence/verb] + noun in Japanese. While attempting to translate the following sentence, I found three of the above construct as denoted by (1) (2) and (3), where the relative clause and main clause meet.

> 自分の置かれた(**1**)状況を把握{はあく}しようとして、混乱している(**2**)うちに殺されていた(**3**)はずよ。

Number 3 seemed suspicious to me and not quite right to be a instance of the relative-main clause construct, so I did some research. [This answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69446/%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%88) says that はず (in most cases) is a  形式名詞 ("formal noun"), which made me wonder if it is possible to make relative-main clause constructs using formal nouns as opposed to normal nouns.

And if the answer is 'yes', is the above instance of はず making a relative-main clause construct? If not, why (in the case it is a formal noun in the above instance, but still fails to make a clause)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. You can even say 形式名詞 is always preceded by a modifier, which is usually a relative clause (and sometimes an attributive like それ, あの). Some 形式名詞 like とき work without a modifier, in which case they are not called 形式名詞.

> - 彼が猫を見るとき when he watches a cat
>     (↑ This とき is a formal noun)
> - ときは来た。 The time has come.
>     (↑ This とき is an ordinary noun)

It is important to understand that 形式名詞 are very often **translated to English without using a noun**. Still, syntactically speaking, they are Japanese nouns, and thus accept relative clauses. Your sentence indeed has three relative clauses marked by (1), (2), and (3).

Other examples of `relative-clause + 形式名詞`:

> - 試験に合格する**ため**に勉強します。
>     I will study to pass the exam.
> - 地球が丸い**こと**を彼は知らなかった。
>     He did not know the fact that the earth is round
> - 言われる**まま**払った。
>     I paid as I was told to.
> - テレビを見る**の**が好きです。
>     I like watching TV.

The last example is also known as a nominalizer, but の is a perfect 形式名詞, syntactically speaking.